# How to find sub-procedure usage in RPG on IBM i?

Tags: ibm-midrange, rpgle

If I have a service program with a single module which contains three sub-procedures.  Is there a way to programmatically find the usages of the individual sub-procedures within a library/file?

So something like this:

```
MYLIB/MYSRVPGM  <-- My service program object
  PROC1  <-- My first sub-procedure
  PROC2  <-- My second sub-procedure
  PROC3  <-- My third sub-procedure
```

Then I have an ILE program which uses `PROC1` and `PROC3` but not `PROC2`.

```
MYLIB/MYPGM  <-- My ILE program object which uses PROC1 and PROC3
```

I'm looking for a way to search for `PROC1` or `PROC3` and see the result of `MYLIB/MYPGM` returned.  However a search for `PROC2` should not return a result.

So far, I've tried using `DSPPGMREF`, but that only returns the overall object (IE: `MYLIB/MYSRVPGM`), not the individual sub-procedures used.

Another route I've ventured was using `FNDSTRPDM` but that's just scanning the source for the string `PROC1`.  It could be in a comment and return a false positive.

I know third-party tools exist for this, but they are not viable options at the moment due to cost.  Free or relatively cheap ones may be an option though (I'm just not aware of any). Am I out of luck?

Comment: Unfortunately, I've found development tools on IBM i for things like this to be woefully inadequate when compared to almost any other development environment.  Even those third party tools are nowhere near as reliable as others I've used in other environments.  So far, the most reliable thing I have come up with is simply to do a source search over every source member in the library you are concerned about.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have the modules for the programs, you could use the List Module Information (QBNLMODI) API to get a list of the module imports. https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_73/apis/qbnlmodi.htm

Comment: Thank you @Barara Morris ! I'll have to read through this to figure out how to use it.  This seems like it does exactly what we need.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I know of that might work from existing *PGM / *SRVPGM objects would be to build something around the [debug APIs](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_72/apis/debug1.htm)

You said that third-party tools are not an option, I assume you mean the commercial ones you'd pay a pretty penny for.

What about open source?  Take a look at the Easy/400 [Program library check up](https://www.easy400.net/plcheckup/html/page1.htm)

Comment: Yes, it's the commercial ones where you have to pay an arm and a leg for which are not an option.  Free, or even relatively cheap ones could be considered.  We're just a small shop and can't justify the cost of those commercial ones.  I'll take a look at the options you suggested, hopefully one of them fits our needs, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I use the iSphere plugin within RDi to do this. If you are not using RDi, then you are already behind the eight-ball when it comes to development for IBM i. iSphere doesn't have the direct ability to find imports, but it does have a source search facility that I like better than FNDSTRPDM. You can search a member, a source file, all the source files in a library, or even everything in an RDi filter for a given string.

Yes it is a source search, but, it is relatively easy to tell if something is a comment or not.